# show/hide textbox by change value of combobox

Tags: vb.net

i'm having problem regarding combobox in vb.net,
im trying to show & hide specific text boxes, on the base of an item when it is selected from combobox,
here is the code i'm writing, whats mistake in it?

```
Dim PatSearchID, PatSearchName, PatSearchCat As String

PatSearchID = txtSearchID.Text
PatSearchCat = cmbSearchPat.SelectedItem.ToString()


If PatSearchCat = "RegNo" Then

txtSearchID.Show()
txtSearchName.Hide()


End if
```

kindly correct what the problem is?

Comment: _"kindly correct what the problem is"_ You don't know what the problem is?

Comment: What type is `cmbSearchPat.SelectedItem` and where is the code located?

Comment: cmbSearchPat is a combobox.

Comment: What type is `cmbSearchPat.SelectedItem`?

Comment: what do u mean by type...?

Comment: `Object`, `String`,`Integer`,`MyCustomClass`, `Foo` are types.

Comment: String it was, & thanks for ur attention, its done,
i was not puttng the code in "Selected Index Changed Event" of combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 txtSearchName.Visible = False
```

30chars

Answer (score 0):

instead of this (txtSearchID.Show()  txtSearchName.Hide()) try to use the visible property of textbox